# Declaring a std::string after Unicode to ASCII conversion is giving Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, string, unicode-string, non-ascii-characters, wchar-t

I am trying to take a `wchar_t` string from stdin and then convert it from unicode to ASCII through a function.

The function is somehow not allowing me to use std::string further in the program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <locale>
#include <cstring>
#include <cwchar>
using namespace std;
bool UnicodeToAscii(wchar_t* szUnicode, char* szAscii);
int main()
{
    wchar_t w[100];
    wcin>>w;
    char* c;
    bool x=UnicodeToAscii(w,c);
    cout<<c<<"\n";
    string s="hi";
    return 0;
}
bool UnicodeToAscii(wchar_t* szUnicode, char* szAscii)
{
    int len, i;
    if((szUnicode == NULL) || (szAscii == NULL))
        return false;
    len = wcslen(szUnicode);
    for(i=0;i<len+1;i++)
        *szAscii++ = static_cast<char>(*szUnicode++);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You are **not** converting any Unicode encoding to ASCII here. Unicode is far more complex.

Comment: Other than that, your test input would help. It could be the reason.

Comment: Ok, that might be wrong but I tried to typecast a **wchar_t** to **char** in the function and then I am unable to use std::string in my program. This is quite strange..

Comment: No test input is working.. As soon as i enter a word and press enter, I get a Segmentation fault error

Comment: ...where do you get memory for `char* c;` ? I don´t see anything related to that. (and the check if it is NULL in the function is good, but not enough. It doesn´t need to be NULL if you´ve done nothing at all). And to know how much memory you´ll need, you need to understand the encoding better first...

Comment: you mean adding these 2 lines?
int len=wcslen(w);
char* c=new char[len];

Comment: Depends on the actual encoding and the impplementation of wcslen. And you need a `delete` too if you´re using `new`. ... Please stop now trying to make this function and read something (many things) about Unicode.

Comment: Ok, the above 2 lines work with delete [] c.. Thank You :)

Comment: Except you can´t be sure and you have a memory leak. Great.

Comment: ...and there is still the issue that you maybe have the correct length, but a wrong conversion. *Your code is still wrong, even if you won´t believe me. And depending on the input, it will still crash or make something strange.*

Comment: May I pls know more about it? I need to implement this method of conversion into a bigger program and I may not like such strange behaviours in it

Comment: I can´t write a (thick) book just now. Unicode is *really* far more complex. UTF/UCS? 8, 16, 32? big/little endian? Recognizing the 7bit ASCII part in the multiple bytes of one char? Filtering out additional stuff like extra codepoints for accents? Unifying different kinds of whitespaces and numbers? and many more...

Comment: If you need to do this for school, tell your teacher he´s an idiot (sorry). If you need this for yourself, use LibICU (but even knowing enough to understand it´s documentation will need some time and reading)

Comment: Even the zipped binary-only versions of ICU have more than 10MB, Nobody can write this in one evening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not allocating any memory for `c`, so you are writing character data to random memory and corrupting your program.

You should stop using character arrays and raw pointers, and start using `std::string` and `std::wstring` instead.  Let them manage memory for you.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void UnicodeToAscii(const std::wstring &szUnicode, std::string &szAscii);

int main()
{
    std::wstring w;
    std::wcin >> w; // or std::getline(wcin, w);

    std::string c;
    bool x = UnicodeToAscii(w, c);
    std::cout << c << "\n";

    std::string s = "hi";
    return 0;
}

void UnicodeToAscii(const std::wstring &szUnicode, std::string &szAscii)
{
    szAscii.clear(len);

    int len = szUnicode.length();
    char c;

    szAscii.reserve(len);

    for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        wchar_t w = szUnicode[i];

        if ((w >= 0) && (w < 127))
        {
            // ASCII character
            c = static_cast<char>(w);
        }
        else
        {
            // non-ASCII character
            c = '?';

            // wchar_t is 2 bytes (UTF-16) on some systems,
            // but is 4 bytes (UTF-32) on other systems...
            #if sizeof(wchar_t) == 2
            if ((w >= 0xD800) && (w <= 0xDFFF))
            {
                // skip first unit of a surrogate pair,
                // the loop will skip the second unit...
                ++i;
            }
            #endif
        }

        szAscii.push_back(c);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Of course, this is very rudimentary, and it only handles true ASCII characters (0x00 - 0x7F).  Handling Unicode correctly is much more complex than this.  But this answers your immediate question about why you cannot use `std::string` after calling your function - because you are trashing memory.

Answer (score -1):

- You never allocate memory for `c` before writing to the invalid pointer.
- It's unsafe to `cin >>` to a fixed size array. You might consider `std::wstring`.
- If you want to convert 16-bit characters to 8-bit characters, use UTF-8 encoding in the 8-bit string, not ASCII. If you must use ASCII, you will have to error out if any character is out of range, or else replace it with a placeholder character. However, this leaves you without international support. You should be able to find information on converting UTF-16 to UTF-8 in C++ easily.

Comment: Three things: While it´s true that converting UTF16 to UTF8 is far easier than OPs original plan, who even said that his source data is UTF16? And who said he can use UTF8 for whatever he needs the converted data? And ... `converting Unicode to UTF-8` please not. UTF8 *is* Unicode, just not all of it.

Comment: I suggested three options for storing the converted data in an 8-bit format. I'm not aware of any additional options.

Comment: While I don´t see *three* different conversion methods in your answer, it doesn´t matter because it doesn´t answer the question. (And, a fourth thing: OP doesn´t use cin)

Comment: @deviantfan The first bullet point does answer the question as the problem is that OP did not allocate memory for `c`.